# Publiquie meu sistema no IIS e ele não esta carregando varios arquivos

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Publiquei meu sistema no IIS (localmente) e quando acesso o mesmo, ele não carrega uma gama de arquivos necessários da aplicação. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que publiquei de forma correta, mas não estou conseguindo resolver este problema. Como faço para que seja possível fazer o carregamento de todos estes arquivos? 
OBS: quando compilo o sistema no Visual Studio, da perfeitamente.

Comment: Pelo que pude perceber foi publicado, mas, o endereços dos javascript por exemplo estão errados.

Comment: Como resolvo o problema? Ppois quando publicamos no servidor da sala, conseguimos acessar perfeitamente. So que preciso colocar a aplicação na maquina local agora rodando no IIS local

Comment: Depende como está processando e incluindo os javascript porque assim no endereço tem uma pasta e na chamada do seu script não tem? talvez o ponto seja ai.

Comment: Este é um exemplo de como estou fazendo as chamadas dos arquivos:
    <link href="/vendors/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @JeffersonSouza No IIS, você criou um novo site ou configurou, adicionou um novo aplicativo ou apenas colocou seu conteúdo no diretório "autonav" dentro da pasta inetpub\wwwroot ???

Comment: @LeandroAngelo sim!

Comment: @JeffersonSouza Qual das opções? :P

Comment: inetpub\wwwroot

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro passo que você pode tentar é simplesmente converter o seu diretório para um aplicativo.

Abra o gerenciador do IIS (digite inetmgr no "executar" do windows)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ainda assim pode ser necessário alguns ajustes na sua aplicação para a baseURL

Outra alternativa é criar um novo site utilizando outra porta e apontando para o seu diretório. Se esse servidor vai rodar só esse site, no Default Web Site altere o caminho mapeado para o seu diretório e seja feliz.

Comment: Ja fiz isto, ai da os erros
 [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpLLu.png [/link]

Comment: O que você já fez? Alás, como você fez o seu publish?

Comment: Fiz utilizando o visual studio @LeandroAngelo. Eu converti em aplicação ja

Comment: Tentou alguma das outras alternativas?

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente esse erro acontece por executar localmente com um diretório virtual diferente do servidor.

Por exemplo, em sua máquina o endereço é http://localhost/ e no servidor http://servidor/nomedesuaaplicacao/

Caso seja este o problema, basta manter ambos os ambientes com o mesmo diretório virtual.